# Powershell EWS upload eml

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have this code to upload EML files to exchange.

```
#Upload Eml Sample  

$folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)     
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
#Crete Email Object  
$emUploadEmail = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage($service)  
#Read File  
[byte[]]$bdBinaryData1 =  get-content -encoding byte "C:\temp\exportedmail.eml"  
#Set Mime Content in Message  
$emUploadEmail.MimeContent = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MimeContent("us-ascii", $bdBinaryData1);  
#Set Sent Message Flags which means message wont appear as a Draft  
$PR_Flags = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer);  
$emUploadEmail.SetExtendedProperty($PR_Flags,"1")  
$emUploadEmail.Save($Inbox.Id)
```

When I try to upload a EML file with an attachment it will crash the computer running the script. It takes all the memory. How can I modify the code above to upload the eml and the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit for solution:  **Glen Scales** provides a solution here:

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to_22.html#!/2012/02/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to_22.html

Replace Get-Content:

`[byte[]]$bdBinaryData1 =  get-content -encoding byte "C:\temp\exportedmail.eml"`

with

`[byte[]]$bdBinaryData1 = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\exportedmail.eml")`